# Limpar tabela do banco de dados

Tags: android, sqlite

uso este método para apagar um registo do banco

```
public boolean delete(String id) {
    String where = "id = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {id};

    int retorno = this.banco.delete("pessoa", where, whereArgs);

    if(retorno != 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

agora to precisando criar um que apaga todos os registros , alguém sabe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso, remover onde for diferente de NULL. Como todo registro provavelmente deve ter um id, então removerá todos.

`String where = "id IS NOT NULL";`

```
public boolean deleteAll() {
    String where = "id IS NOT NULL";
    this.banco.delete("pessoa", where, null);
}
```

Comment: funcionou obrigado